# MSSQL - group the time between start/end columns by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Couldn't find anything by searching (though that may be my search terms) so apologies if this has been asked/answered.

We maintain a log of equipment downtime in MSSQL 2012, and I'm trying to report minutes of downtime grouped by day, equipment, DTCode. The problem I'm running in to is the log table contains start & end dates for each incident and incidents frequently span multiple days (or sometimes weeks) between the start and end.

Example Data:

```
Start           End             Equipment    DTCode
01/01/15 00:00  01/02/15 02:00  Line1        2
```

Desired Result:

```
Date          Equipment      DTCode   Downtime(minutes)
01/01/15      Line1          2        1440
01/02/15      Line1          2        120
```

**EDIT**

Ok, now I have an inelegant solution with poor performance, because the only way I could figure it is by using a nested cursor. Here's a new fiddle with a larger dataset and the functional solution I'm looking to tweak/optimize:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b287e/1

Answer (score 0):

If you mean getting the time between the two "Downtime"s, you can get the values with PHP using MYSQL connection, and calculate the difference, and then delete the two rows, and replace it with a new row, with the calculated results.

```
$query = "DELETE FROM TaBlEnAmEhErE WHERE DTCode=2";
```

Answer (score 0):

When I started testing the solution I came up with against production data performance was a lot more acceptable, so I'm going to roll with it for now limiting users to a 1 year scope of data for the report.

In addition to the log data, I created a table containing dates from 2010-2050 so I didn't have to generate the dates each run, this is what I came up with:

```
--Variables for outer cursor
DECLARE @ID INT
,@StartDate DATETIME
,@EndDate DATETIME
,@LineID TINYINT
,@DTCode SMALLINT
--Table var to hold results
DECLARE @ResultTbl AS TABLE (
    [Date] DATE
    ,Line TINYINT
    ,DTCode SMALLINT
    ,MinDiff INT
)
--Declare cursor to loop through log data
DECLARE IDCur CURSOR local fast_forward FOR
SELECT ID
    ,StartTime
    ,EndTime
    ,EquipmentID
    ,dtcode
FROM DowntimeLog
OPEN IDCur
    FETCH NEXT FROM IDCur INTO @ID, @StartDate, @EndDate, @LineID, @DTCode
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        --Check if the entry spans multiple days
        IF DATEDIFF(DAY,@StartDate,@EndDate) > 0
        BEGIN
            --Declare cursor to loop through each date that pertains to the entry
            DECLARE @D DATE
            DECLARE applicableDates CURSOR LOCAL fast_forward FOR
            SELECT tDate
            FROM DateTbl
            WHERE tDate BETWEEN CAST(@StartDate AS DATE) AND CAST(@EndDate AS DATE)
            OPEN applicableDates
            FETCH NEXT FROM applicableDates INTO @D
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                --Determine if @D is the first date
                IF (SELECT CAST(@StartDate AS DATE)) = @D
                BEGIN
                    --If @D is the first date insert result row with minutes between start & 00:00 the next day
                    INSERT INTO @ResultTbl (
                            [Date]
                            ,Line
                            ,DTCode
                            ,MinDiff)
                        VALUES (
                            @D
                            ,@LineID
                            ,@DTCode
                            ,(SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@StartDate,DATEADD(DAY,1,@D))))
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    --Determine if @D is the last date
                    IF (SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@D,@EndDate)) < 1440
                    BEGIN
                        --If @D is the last date insert result row with minutes between @D 00:00 and end of downtime
                        INSERT INTO @ResultTbl (
                            [Date]
                            ,Line
                            ,DTCode
                            ,MinDiff)
                        VALUES (
                            @D
                            ,@LineID
                            ,@DTCode
                            ,(SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@D,@EndDate)))
                    END
                    ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        --If @D is not first or last date insert result row for the full day
                        INSERT INTO @ResultTbl (
                            [Date]
                            ,Line
                            ,DTCode
                            ,MinDiff)
                        VALUES (
                            @D
                            ,@LineID
                            ,@DTCode
                            ,1440)
                    END
                END
                FETCH NEXT FROM applicableDates INTO @D
            END
            CLOSE applicableDates
            DEALLOCATE applicableDates
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            --Entry does not span multiple days, insert result row with diff between start & end
            INSERT INTO @ResultTbl (
                            [Date]
                            ,Line
                            ,DTCode
                            ,MinDiff)
                        VALUES (
                            CAST(@StartDate AS DATE)
                            ,@LineID
                            ,@DTCode
                            ,(SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@StartDate,@EndDate)))
        END
        FETCH NEXT FROM IDCur INTO @ID, @StartDate, @EndDate, @LineID, @DTCode
    END
CLOSE IDCur
DEALLOCATE IDCur
--Display Result
SELECT [Date]
        ,Line
        ,DTCode
        ,SUM(MinDiff) AS MinDown
FROM @ResultTbl
GROUP BY [Date],Line,DTCode
```